# Write XML to ZIP

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to pack two XML files into a zip file:
The XMLs are generated with `org.w3c.dom.*` and I am trying to directly transform them into a `ZipOutputStream`. Single file example:

```
public InputStream getStream() {
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
        var zipEntry = new ZipEntry("file1.xml");
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        final Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        final Element root = document.createElement("root");
        document.appendChild(root);
        final DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        final StreamResult result = new StreamResult(zos);
        final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        final Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

final ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(getStream());
final ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
assertEquals("file1.xml", entry.getName());// still ok
final String xmlString = IOUtils.toString(zis);//throws: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
assertThat(xmlString, containsString("root");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Without the code that reads it is hard to tell what is happening. To validate the file, you can also try to extract the content externally, `zip` or even double-clicking in most OSes should tell you if it is a valid zip or not.

Comment: @khachik The OS also says it is an invalid ZIP file. So I debugged it in Java, where I see the entries but apparently no proper data associated to them. I'll add the debugging info to the question.

Comment: please add the code that creates the transformer and the document as well.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Move bos declaration and return outside of the try block. At present zos isn't closed at the time you call `bos.toByteArray()` so it is corrupt zip.

Comment: Side note:  All of those `final` occurrences are doing nothing besides making the code harder to read.  All local variables are already effectively final unless assigned a second time.

Comment: @VGR I know, but these are the coding rules on this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as you have it creates the input stream before the zip output stream is closed, as `zos` is not closed until after `return`. Just pull out the declaration of `bos` and `return` out of the try block like this:

```
try (final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    try (final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
        var zipEntry = new ZipEntry("file1.xml");
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        // Do your work with transform
    }
    // At this point, "zos" is definitely closed properly
    // and bos has complete bytes of the zip.
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
}
```

You can demonstrate the issue by comparing the output of these calls:

```
// Reports incorrect byte length for the ZIP inside the try block
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
        var zipEntry = new ZipEntry("file1.xml");
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        zos.write(("<root>"+"<other></other>".repeat(100)+"</root>").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("bos size is "+bos.toByteArray().length);
    } 

}
```

Whereas this reports the proper size:

```
// Reports correct byte length for the ZIP in outer try block
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        try (final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
            var zipEntry = new ZipEntry("file1.xml");
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zos.write(("<root>"+"<other></other>".repeat(100)+"</root>").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            System.out.println("bos size is "+bos.toByteArray().length);
        } 
        System.out.println("bos size is "+bos.toByteArray().length);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Still not sure why the unit test was happy but the actual use case generated an invalid ZIP file. Now with the nested try-with it works in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

First, you are catching and ignoring `Exception`. Depending on what fails and where it may not generate a valid zip entry.
Second, the code you posted will generate empty output, the transformer doesn't have a stylesheet (but this won't cause invalid zip entry if everything else is correct).

Comment: That is just for the example, we have some custom exceptions that are thrown which are not really relevant here. And it does not throw an exception, I get a valid ZipInputStream in my UnitTest with the expected entries, just the content is invalid.

Comment: We can only comment on/help with the code you post here @Thomas.

Comment: Not correct.  The [newTransformer() method that takes no arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer()) returns an identity transformation.  It will not generate empty output.